# Two tables to one table as relation

Tags: database, postgresql, algorithm, design-patterns

I have some troubles to design a part of my database and the relationship between them.

My entities are:

- Vehicles -> 1:1 -> Prices
- Bikes -> 1:1 -> Prices

**Option A:**

Create 2 tables

VEHICLES TABLE

```
+----------------+---------+
|      NAME      |  TYPE   |
+----------------+---------+
| Id             | uuid    |
| brand          | varchar |
| model          | varchar |
| attribute1     | varchar |
| price          | float   |
| discount float |         |
| locale varchar |         |
+----------------+---------+
```

BIKES TABLE

```
+----------------+---------+
|      NAME      |  TYPE   |
+----------------+---------+
| Id             | uuid    |
| vendor         | varchar |
| attribute1     | varchar |
| attribute2     | varchar |
| attribute3     | varchar |
| price          | float   |
| discount float |         |
| locale varchar |         |
+----------------+---------+
```

**Option B**

Create 3 tables

VEHICLES TABLE

```
+----------------+---------+
|      NAME      |  TYPE   |
+----------------+---------+
| Id             | uuid    |
| brand          | varchar |
| model          | varchar |
| attribute1     | varchar |
+----------------+---------+
```

BIKES TABLE

```
+----------------+---------+
|      NAME      |  TYPE   |
+----------------+---------+
| Id             | uuid    |
| vendor         | varchar |
| attribute1     | varchar |
| attribute2     | varchar |
| attribute3     | varchar |
+----------------+---------+
```

PRICES TABLE

```
+----------------+-------+
|      NAME      | TYPE  |
+----------------+-------+
| vehicle_id     | FK    |
| bike_id        | FK    |
| price          | float |
| discount float |       |
| locale varchar |       |
+----------------+-------+
```

**Option C**

create 4 tables

VEHICLES TABLE

```
+----------------+---------+
|      NAME      |  TYPE   |
+----------------+---------+
| Id             | uuid    |
| brand          | varchar |
| model          | varchar |
| attribute1     | varchar |
+----------------+---------+
```

VEHICLES_PRICES TABLE

```
+----------------+-------+
|      NAME      | TYPE  |
+----------------+-------+
| vehicle_id     | FK    |
| price          | float |
| discount float |       |
| locale varchar |       |
+----------------+-------+
```

BIKES TABLE

```
+----------------+---------+
|      NAME      |  TYPE   |
+----------------+---------+
| Id             | uuid    |
| vendor         | varchar |
| attribute1     | varchar |
| attribute2     | varchar |
| attribute3     | varchar |
+----------------+---------+
```

BIKE_PRICES TABLE

```
+----------------+-------+
|      NAME      | TYPE  |
+----------------+-------+
| bike_id        | FK    |
| price          | float |
| discount float |       |
| locale varchar |       |
+----------------+-------+
```

*NOTE: I really simplify the vehicles & bikes tables (i can't merge this both in one table like 'product')*

What we will be the best design for the **performance** and **pattern** point of view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option B is fine if you need to have all prices in a single table (for sorting etc), although you'll probably want to have a constraint on the prices table that each row references exactly either a vehicle or a bike, but neither both nor none of them.

Notice that here you could have vehicles or bikes that don't have a price.

The alternative is to invert the foreign key relation, and have three tables like this:

```
PRODUCTS TABLE
+----------------+---------+
|      NAME      | TYPE    |
+----------------+---------+
| product_id     | uuid    |
| price          | float   |
| discount       | float   |
| locale         | varchar |
+----------------+---------+
```

```
VEHICLES TABLE
+----------------+---------+
|      NAME      |  TYPE   |
+----------------+---------+
| Id             | uuid,FK |
| brand          | varchar |
| model          | varchar |
| attribute1     | varchar |
+----------------+---------+
```

```
BIKES TABLE
+----------------+---------+
|      NAME      |  TYPE   |
+----------------+---------+
| Id             | uuid,FK |
| vendor         | varchar |
| attribute1     | varchar |
| attribute2     | varchar |
| attribute3     | varchar |
+----------------+---------+
```

Now you could have products that are neither bikes nor vehicles, and you could have products that are bike and vehicle at the same time. The disadvantage is that for a given product you don't know which it is.

On the other hand, this scheme allows enforcing that every vehicle and every bike has a price.

---

Since you asked about a pattern point of view, the solution from that regard would be to use a [composite type for your prices](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html). A price isn't an entity (with its own identity), it's a just a value that is used by bikes and vehicles. Here we would have only two tables:

```
PRICE _TYPE_
+----------------+---------+
|      NAME      | TYPE    |
+----------------+---------+
| value          | float   |
| discount       | float   |
| locale         | varchar |
+----------------+---------+
```

```
VEHICLES TABLE
+----------------+---------+
|      NAME      |  TYPE   |
+----------------+---------+
| Id             | uuid,FK |
| brand          | varchar |
| model          | varchar |
| attribute1     | varchar |
| price          | price   |
+----------------+---------+
```

```
BIKES TABLE
+----------------+---------+
|      NAME      |  TYPE   |
+----------------+---------+
| Id             | uuid,FK |
| vendor         | varchar |
| attribute1     | varchar |
| attribute2     | varchar |
| attribute3     | varchar |
| price          | price   |
+----------------+---------+
```

This would be equivalent to your solution A, although with better code reuse. Also a `price` field is now nullable as a complete structure, not on its individual parts.

However, from a performance and usability perspective I would recommend to avoid the composite types, they're a hassle to work with. You'd rather go with solution A and keep the price-related column definitions in sync manually.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with Option B, since you can't merge both. This way you can have multiple prices and/or keep records of price changes in the future.

Comment: thanks, but I know my relation will be always a 1:1. 

And it's is a bad practice to generate by design NULL values?

I mean the PRICES_TABLES will have have one the FK as NULL (each time vehicle_id is not null bike_id will be null and vice-versa)

Answer (score 0):

If you can divide your id range into two parts (for example, less than 50000000 for bikes and greater than 50000000 for vehicles, then go for the option B. This avoids creating unused null columns. 
Otherwise, the option C provides better flexibility to changes as the data needed for bikes and cars changes differently in the future. 
You can also keep the history of prices by adding additional DateTime column/s to the price table/s.